# How to map values in sublist of list in r

Tags: r, list, function, sublist

Im fairly new to R. I'm trying to apply a function to a value in a sublist that I got, but I don't know where to look.

I read some json files in R like so:

```r
library("rjson")
fileNames <- list.files(path = "/<PATH>/TimedSentences", full.names = TRUE)
parseJson <- function(fileName){
  fromJSON(file = fileName)
}

jsons <- lapply(fileNames, parseJson)

jsonToSentJson <- function(jsonList){
  #change sentences to sentiments
}
```

The json files look a little like this

```
{
  "name": "<STORYNAME>",
  "sentences": [
    {
      "beginTime": 880,
      "endTime": 16960,
      "sentence": "Okay, guys, here we go."
    },
    {
      "beginTime": 14160,
      "endTime": 16960,
      "sentence": "Here we go."
    },...]
}
```

Now I want to get almost the same list back, except that I want to run a function against each sentence value and change it into a sentiment value. I got a package installed that has a function called "get_sentiment" and I basically write a json file that looks a little like this:

```
{
  "name": "<MOVIENAME>",
  "sentences": [
    {
      "beginTime": 880,
      "endTime": 16960,
      "sentiment": 1.5
    },
    {
      "beginTime": 14160,
      "endTime": 16960,
      "sentiment": 0.0
    },...]
}
```

What should I look for when I'm trying to do this?

NB: I can figure out how to write the jsn file I think, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to change the value in the sublist

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

I did it with

```
jsonSentencesToJsonSentiment <- function(json){
    list("name" = json[["name"]], 
     "sentiments" =lapply(json[["sentences"]], timedSentenceToTimedSentiment)
     )
}

timedSentenceToTimedSentiment <- function(timedSentence){
  list("beginTime" = timedSentence[["beginTime"]], 
    "endTime" = timedSentence[["endTime"]],
    "sentiment" = get_sentiment(c(timedSentence[["sentence"]]), method = "nrc"))
}

sentJson <- lapply(jsons, jsonSentencesToJsonSentiment)
```